# The token obtained from the Token Provider is wrong Error occur

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

Azure notification hub show error while send test message.Using Push notification service in Xamarin.Form UWP app. Notification not receive message in Xamarin.Forms UWP. When send test message its show error "The token obtained from the Token Provider is wrong".

Answer (score 3):

Typically, the error message indicates that the credentials configured in Notification Hubs are invalid or that there's an issue with the registrations in the hub. 
Kindly review the app id/key and then re-try. 
Or delete this registration and let the client re-create the registration before sending the message. 
Hope this helps. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: How do we delete the registrations ? Does Azure provide some API for this ?